# htaccess conditional rewrites on files not found but based on specific directories provided in url

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Not fully sure if this is possible or not, but Ive been tasked with rebuilding a handful of sites that, their internal workings is a mystery as to how they are still functional. Raised before MVC, CMS, etc were even really known about. In the days of PHP 4 on the cusp of 3, if that gives you any idea. So.. I have a mess, a big on, that I am trying to rebuild using a MVC, which thats not really the problem.

The problem is, is the 20,000 or so files and images that have been stored in articles, and various other things on this site over the ages. So there is sites every where that have hotlinked images and other files, not to mention the hardcoded urls in the articles, which will eventually be converted correctly but theres so many.

Anyway. Bottom line is I wanna know if theres a means of mean taking failed image and file requests and mapping them to a new folder that will have either all these images or files in them. Is this something htaccess can do alone or is this something I will have to come up with a means of serverside script and htaccess? or is it the worst case where I am going to have to take the hit for files not found, and route them all to a single error page, saying the files have been moved?

Not sure what would be a good course of action for this problem so I havent tried anything yet, kinda trying to feel it out and see where I have to go from there.

Comment: Well it looks like you have real mess there. I would try to write some code that would search for "hardcoded links" to files; move file in new folder; replace the script.. Not sure how it looks like but I would try it that way; that would whole process easier and faster...

Comment: In the long run I am going to have to write a script that will dig through the files and change hardcoded values. This htaccess is in sorts a two part fix, one for the temporary, and two for the missed ones. I'd rather catch them by some means then have my logs filled up with thousands of lines from missing files, but this sites rebuild requires the restructuring, and so much more, worth the BS.. and definately worth what Im getting paid for it, but again rather than have a mess of broken images, im searching for a means to an end while everything else is going on :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use redirection for all image extensions to specific folder:

```
RewriteRule (.*)\.(gif|jpg|png)$ /my/new/folder/$1.$2 [R,L]
```

Hope this helps...